# Combining two custom commands

Tags: macros

I came across a problem when typing my report. I do not know how to fix this. The problem is as follows:

I have two custom commands defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\slr}[1][n]{\ensuremath{{\bf SL}(#1,\mathbb{R})}}

\newcommand{\lie}[1][G]{\ensuremath{{\bf L}(#1)}}
```

So that the first command gives an output like `${\bf SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$` and the second command gives the output like `${\bf L}(G)$`. Here `$n$` and `$G$` are respectively the default arguments.

Now when I use these two commands together, I hope to get

```
$${\bf L}({\bf SL}(2,\mathbb{R}))$$
```

However, for some reason what I am getting is

```
$$ {\bf L}({\bf SL}(2),\mathbb{R})$$
```

Any ideas of what is going on here?

Comment: In LaTeX, don't use `\bf`; use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}` or `\mathbf{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in `\lie[\slr[2]]` is that the optional argument to `\lie` is taken to be `\slr[2`. You can solve the issue with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\slrop}{\mathbf{SL}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lieop}{\mathbf{L}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\slr}{O{n}}{\slrop(#1,\mathbb{R})}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lie}{O{G}}{\lieop(#1)}

\begin{document}
Here it is: $\lie[\slr]$

With optional argument: $\lie[\slr[2]]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed `\ensuremath` as I believe that you gain nothing from using `\lie` in text rather than `$\lie$`; to the contrary, I firmly believe that the latter form is much better, because math is always treated as math.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\slr[1][n]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{SL}(#1,\mathbb{R})}}
\newcommand\lie[1][G]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{L}}(#1)}

\begin{document}

\[ {\bf L}({\bf SL}(2,\mathbb{R})) \]

\[ \lie[{\slr[2]}] \]

\[ \slr[\lie] \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to put the optional argument into braces: `[{\slr[2]}]`

Comment: I am still getting the same problem. I am using the book class, if that helps.

Comment: Also, as suggested above, I am now using \textbf instead of \bf.

Comment: see myedited answer.

Comment: It works by putting {} around the second argument.

Comment: As i already wrote .... :-)

Comment: Could you tell me the reason for this?

Comment: `[\slr[2]]` takes the first `]` as closing brace for the first `[` and not for the second one, because `[` looks only for a following `]`